# Use an existing database connexion in a tJava component

Tags: talend

I'm looking for a way to Call an existing database connxion in a tJava Component.
I have created a new BDD connexion in the JAVA Bloc , but this new connexion not permit me to use the data insert with the tMySqlConnexion Component because the first connexion do his commit at the end of the job.
I need to use in the JAVA bloc the same connexion using in the tMySqlConnexion.

Thank you for you help !

Comment: Do you know that you can enable/disable the auto-commit feature on a `tMySQLConnection` component ? Doing that, you can use the `tCommit` component explicitly.

Comment: Yes i know , But i have two differents session (tMysqlConnexion and an other in the tJava) , my tCommit component is linking with tMysqlConnexion . I would to use the same connexion in my tVava

Comment: I would say that it's not a good practise to open a connection in tJava. IMHO, It goes against Talend's logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tMysqlConnection component stores the connection in the job's globalMap. You can retrieve it from there and use it in your tJava component, like so:

```
java.sql.Connection c = (java.sql.Connection)globalMap.get("conn_tMysqlConnection_1");
```

This assumes that your tMysqlConnection has the unique name tMysqlConnection_1; change this to the actual name used in your job.